# Error al intentar acceder a una url con el método page.click() de Playwright

Tags: python, web-scrapping

Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
def handler(event, pin):
    print(event)
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(args=["--single-process"], headless=False)
        browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(event["url"])
        page.click("a:has-text('Certificado de Tradición')")
        page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
        page.click("a:has-text('Validar Certificado Tradicion')", timeout=60000)
        page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
        page.fill("input[name='pin']", pin)
        page.click("button[type='Validar']")
        page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
```

al ejecutar mi prueba,
la url inicial se abre correctamente: *https://www.supernotariado.gov.co/*

Después hace clic en la sección: *Certificado de Tradición* y me lleva a la siguiente url: *https://certificados.supernotariado.gov.co/certificado*. Después debería hacer clic en la parte de *Validar Certificado Tradicion* y mandarme a otra url, pero he allí mi problema, que no abre la url y me marca error:

```
ERROR: test_handler (src.controllers.tests.test_validate_pin.TestValidatePin.test_handler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\playwright\src\controllers\tests\test_validate_pin.py", line 11, in test_handler
    handler(
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\playwright\src\controllers\download_info_pin.py", line 17, in handler
    page.click("a:has-text('Validar Certificado Tradicion')", timeout=60000)
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 10171, in click
    self._sync(
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 109, in _sync
    return task.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_page.py", line 691, in click
    return await self._main_frame.click(**locals_to_params(locals()))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 483, in click
    await self._channel.send("click", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 61, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 482, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\LEGALITICA\playwright\env\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 97, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 60000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("a:has-text('Validar Certificado Tradicion')")
```

La estructura del html es la siguiente:

```html
<div>
  <a href="/certificado/external/validation/validate.snr">
    <div>
      <div>
        <img
          alt="Icono Validar"
          src="/certificado/javax.faces.resource/images/icons/icon-validate-inicio.png.snr"
          style="height: 38px"
        />
        <div>Validar Certificado Tradicion</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

No sé si estoy tratando de acceder incorrectamente a la url o cuál sea el problema.

Comment: Y porque no accedes a la url directamente ???

Comment: Intentas localizar el enlace por su texto, pero el texto está en uno de los divs anidados.